# Splitting Digital RGB Signal Line to multiple LED strips

Tags: signal, led-strip, rgb, split

I am trying to connect multiple strings of WS2812B RGB LEDs to the same signal line (so that they will all behave the same way, display the same colors, etc). The WS2812B is very time sensitive, so I am looking for input on the most effective way to take the single signal line, and split it to all 4 strips. All of the strips are identical. Thanks for any help!

Comment: These modules are designed to be serially cascaded by connecting `Dout`s to the `Din`s. This is the right method.

Comment: Yea, the issue is that I'm limited by the software that I am using (and dont have the ability to change). The software supports up to 32 LEDs, but I'm trying to use 4 32-LED-strings, all doing the same thing. One string works great, I'm just trying to find a solution for all 4.

Comment: So your LED strips are cascaded as mentioned?

Comment: I think that I may not be understanding you 100% (sorry about that). The 4 strips are currently independent of eachother. It sounds like you are talking about wiring the output from the last LED from Strand 1, to the first LED input of Strand 2, etc. If that is what you are saying, then no, they are not currently connected like that. I do appreciate your help though, so if you need me to clarify my setup further please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to understand how each of the strips are interconnected. Each has 32 LEDs, right? So they have to be interconnected somehow.

Comment: Ahh ok. So, I have 4 strands, each with 32 WS2812B LEDs. Each strand has the LEDs connected as dout -> din. What I am trying to do is make them all share the same initial data-in line.

Comment: Ok, I see. According to the datasheet the input current on `Din` is `1uA` at max, so I believe you could simply split the line and your micro will be able to drive it most likely.

Comment: Connect them in parallel with the same length wires.

Answer (score 1):

Two simple methods. The inputs are typical high-impedence signal inputs, so its not hard to drive multiple from one gpio output.

1. Just split your output at the first led.
2. Use one led as a buffer, and split it at that point. Adjust by 1 for your strip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feKeXK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Try to keep the cable length between your output and the led DIN as short as possible to prevent any sync issues.